# Move vertical scroll from page to inner div

Tags: html, css

I have a page without vertical scroll on `<html` element. I mean no matter how you zoom - it will adjust to screen size and there always be

- red div on top (with inner content) with fixed height
- dynamically expanded height green div on bottom (its height depends on inner content).
- Between those divs there's 1 more div with 2 children (with yellow background) that have scrollable content. This div should fluid the rest of space.

To remove page's scroll I just feet the html height perfectly to its inner elements sum by using **`height: calc(100% - 83px)`** where `83px` is top and bottom divs height sum. But here's a problem: when the bottom div's height increases I need to change scrollable center div's height with javascript. **I want to solve this only using `css`**. Here's [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f2k806b3/) and the picture described by layout.
[image]
What I found so far:

- I think that parent div should have some kind of `overflow:auto;` for children and a tricky **?**`height: 100%` and children must have `height: 100%'
- I can't use absolute position because I don't know where the central div should start and end vertically

The code is listed below:

```
<style>
.fluid-inline {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    /*I WANT TO REMOVE HARDCODED 83px SIZE */
    height: calc(100% - 83px); /*SUM nav + footer height.*/
    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}
.scrollable {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
</style>

<nav></nav>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fluid-inline">
        <div class="scrollable left"></div>
        <div class="scrollable"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
</div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/ . This tutorial teaches how to customize the scrollbar with an easy script.. Take a look..

Comment: I want to use native scrollbar. Anyway I'ma read the article, thanks for the link!

Comment: @deathangel908 I think JavaScript is necessary for this to happen, as you are asking for the bottom div(green) to have dynamic height. So depending on inner content height of that div would vary, which could be achieved by JS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a flex-box solution. It requires some love and care to get it to work on all modern browsers so take a look at [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for info about this.

It is worth pointing out that this does not work with old browser version at all and that a JavaScript substitute will be required if support is essential.

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
#wrapper{
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
#header{
  height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}
#content{
  flex:1;  
  display: flex;
  min-height: 0; // FF FIX
  background-color:yellow;
}
.scrollable{
  width: 50%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
#footer{
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```